# How to export datatables in multiple tabs in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatable, export-to-excel

I have 2 tabs in my laravel project. I want to export my datatable to excel.
First datatable id is #listRepairOut, and the second is #listRepair.

I have successfully export the datatables to excel. But the problem is, my datatable in the last tab is broken. The table header is moving, so it seems not good.

Here I attach the views:

[image: Unpaid tab = #listRepairOut]

[image: Paid tab = #listRepair]

And this is my javascript that I used to export datatables:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#listRepairOut').DataTable({
        scrollX: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        "paging": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info": false,
        "searching": false,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'excel'
        ],
    });
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#listRepair').DataTable({
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            "paging": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            "searching": false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'excel'
            ],
        });
    });

    $('.nav-tabs a:last').click(function () {
        $(this).tab('show');
        $('#listRepairOut').DataTable().draw();
    })
```

What should I do to fix this broken datatable? I want to fix the second table like the first table. Please help me

Comment: There is a very well documented library that does this for you using your datatables, also datatables has an export to excel functions as well, take a look at this https://laravel-excel.com/

Comment: i dont use maatwebsite, i only use simple javascript on the script section, like the previous code that I write. I've already get the exported file in excel file. The problem is, the datatables that contain my blade is broken because i use this javascript @KhalilGhanem